# «Был ещё один, нижний подвал...» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, определения, уточнения

> Под подвалом этого дома, оказывается, был ещё **один, нижний(,) подвал**, в котором были три большие комнаты — чистые, обставленные мебелью и, очевидно, обитаемые.

Достаточно ли запятой перед словом "нижний" или же следовало бы выделить его запятыми с обеих сторон? Предложение из компьютерной игры, пунктуация в переводе не всегда корректная.

Comment: Вполне достаточно. Либо нужно писать: один (нижний) подвал. Если обособить нижний, то получится прилагательное без определяемого слова, подвешенное в воздухе. Ну и можно еще: ещё один - нижний подвал, - обойтись тире, если хочется поставить акцент на нижнем подвале.

Comment: @Буратино Если обособить "нижний", то получится "под подвалом был еще один подвал". По-моему, вполне корректно звучит.

Comment: Не может быть подвал под подвалом. Потому что под подвалом тоже подвал, это всё - подвал. Подвал - это не место, а прежде всего понятие. Находящееся под наземной частью дома, в земле, ниже уровня земли. все находящееся  - это подвал.

Comment: @Буратино Если под подвалом не может быть подвала, может ли под подвалом быть _нижний подвал_?

Comment: Может быть нижний, но это тоже подвал. Подвал - это общее название помещений ниже уровня земли, понятие такое, подвал. Особенно когда подвалов больше, чем один. То есть это "тот же самый подвал", а не какой-то другой подвал. Подвал относящийся к этому дому, а не к другому.

Comment: "Под подвалом этого дома, оказывается, был ещё один - нижний,  в котором были три большие комнаты — чистые, обставленные мебелью и, очевидно, обитаемые. " Наверное, вот так лучше сделать, убрав "подвал, подвал", оставив один подвал.

Comment: Кстати, вы же вот не пишите: в котором были три большие комнаты, чистые комнаты. То есть "комнаты, комнаты" вы не пишите, а "подвал, подвал" - пишите?

Answer (score 1):

Нужна только одна запятая, т.к. здесь поясняющее определение:

> Под подвалом этого дома, оказывается, был ещё **один, нижний** подвал, в
> котором были три большие комнаты — чистые, обставленные мебелью и,
> очевидно, обитаемые.

---

**Правило:**

*Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится:*
Все усилия необходимо было сосредоточить **на одном, северном** направлении;

Comment: У Розенталя в теме об уточнениях есть пример с двумя запятыми. _Уточняющие определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста и т. д.: Ещё одно, **последнее**, сказанье — и летопись окончена моя (П.)_ Получается, поясняющие определения выделяются с одной стороны, уточняющие - с двух сторон. Как определить, какой вид определения в моем вопросе?

Comment: @athlonusm Не знаю даже, как числительное можно здесь "уточнить". "Такой-то" (один) - это и есть нижний, равноправные понятия. Одно и то же называется разными словами. Числительные нехарактерно уточнять. Ради приобщения к западной цивилизации, и в результате Россия превращается в европейскую державу первого ранга. Но по крайней мере один, верхний слой доступен всем. [А. Б. Гребнев. Дневник (1966)]

Comment: В теории можно предположить, что был еще какой-то подвал, тогда получается, что это "один, нижний, подвал", а не, скажем, верхний.

Comment: "Верхний" подвал в данном случае - это, получается, основной подвал, а под ним находится "нижний" подвал.